# How to prioritize first row in flex-wrap?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using `flex-wrap`, which gives me output like
[image]

In this two-column example the container number 5 in the last row grows.
However, the first containers are usually more important than the last.
So how can I priorise them? I considered [`flex-direction: row-reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) without success.

It should work also for say, 3 columns and 8 containers, in which case the first two should grow (not the last two).
All containers should have the same size in case the number of containers is a integer multiple of the column numbers .

And the code for the example above

```css
div > div {
  background-color: #3b3;
  flex: 1 1 40%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; gap: 10px;">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when 5 you want the first to grow instead of the 5th ?

Comment: @Temani Afif, yes the first container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use specific selector to achieve this:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.box > div {
  background-color: #3b3;
  flex: 1 1 40%;
}
/* make the first child full width if there is an odd number of elements */
.box > div:nth-last-child(odd):first-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

For a 3 columns configuration, you use the same logic

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.box > div {
  background-color: #3b3;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
}
/* the first child full width when we have 3N + 1 elements */
.box > div:nth-last-child(3n + 1):first-child {
  flex-basis:100%;
}
/* first and second child half width when we have 3N + 2 elements */
.box > div:nth-last-child(3n + 2):first-child,
.box > div:nth-last-child(3n + 2):first-child + *{
  flex-basis: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Since I have only two or three columns, that is a nice solution for me.